# Tunneling requests via an ssh connection in php

Tags: php, proxy, ssl, ssh-tunnel

Given an ssh tunnel created on machine A to machine B using e.g.

```
ssh -D 9999 user@remote-server-ip-machine-B
```

In php how would one make requests from machine A to machine C using stream_socket_client() such that those requests are made via the above tunnel e.g.

```
$socket = stream_socket_client("tls://$ip-machine-C:$port", $errno,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```

In other words, the requests must originate from a php script running on machine A made to machine C but to machine C the requests must look like they are coming from machine B (the connection made to machine C needs to be made using tls).

Or alternatively, is there a way to achieve the same end result directly in php without the ssh tunnel? Any help with this will be very much appreciated

Comment: Do to the lack of response to the above question and after doing some more research, I am now trying to find a way to get php to make any external network requests through a socks proxy i.e. if I can get this right then I can get stream_socket_client() to make its requests via the ssh tunnel. Any assistance on this specific question would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best way to solve this problem is to use a VPN like [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) (connecting machine A to machine B) or a very useful script called [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle), which is a transparent proxy server that works as a poor man's VPN.